# Functions assigning result variable showing me this error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
res = ' '
def paper_doll(text):
    for i in text:
        res = res+i+i+i
    return res
paper_doll('Hello')
```

Error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'res' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Although `res` is defined at the module level as a global variable, the fact that `res` is used as an assignee of an assignment statement in the `paper_doll` function makes the Python compiler mark it as a local variable within the scope of the `paper_doll` function block, so when it evaluates `res+i+i+i` during the first iteration of the `for` loop, it finds `res` uninitialized as `res` is not yet assigned with a value at that point.

As it is generally discouraged to change the value of a global variable from within a function, you should instead name `res` in the `paper_doll` function something else, and initialize it with the global variable `res`:

```
res = ' '
def paper_doll(text):
    r = res
    for i in text:
        r = r+i+i+i
    return r
```

Answer (score 0):

`res` is a global variable and can be accessed but not modified without explicitly specifying `global` within the modifying function.

Or, simpler solution, define `res` *within* the function:

```
def paper_doll(text):
    res = ' ' # or global res
    for i in text:
        res = res+i+i+i
    return res
paper_doll('Hello')
```

Either way, outputs:

```
 HHHeeellllllooo
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions.

1: Tell the function `paper_doll` that the `res` variable you are planning to use inside the function is a global variable by writing `global res` inside the function like so.

```
res = ' '
def paper_doll(text):
    global res
    for i in text:
        res = res+i+i+i
    return res
print(paper_doll('Hello')) 
#HHHeeellllllooo
```

Note that this might be a bad solution, because if you use this `res` variable somewhere else, you might not get the desired value since it is modified by someone else, e.g `func` already modified `res` for you changing the global variable, now when you use it in `paper_doll` you will get an unexpected result

```
res = ' '

def func():
    global res
    res = 'abcd'

def paper_doll(text):
    global res
    for i in text:
        res = res+i+i+i
    return res

func()
print(paper_doll('Hello'))
#abcdHHHeeellllllooo
```

2. Just define a local variable `res=0` inside the function and return it. You can still use res outside the function.
   Here the local `res` was updated correctly, and the global `res` as well, and both didn't affect each other

```
res = ' '

def func():
    global res
    res = 'abcd'

def paper_doll(text):
    res = ''
    for i in text:
        res = res+i+i+i
    return res

func()
print(paper_doll('Hello'))
print(res)
#HHHeeellllllooo
#abcd
```